# Почему у М. Горького тире перед отрицанием?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

В сердце у меня — смутное что-то. И в глазах... И все кажется мне, что это — не настоящее... (Максим Горький).

Почему здесь стоит тире перед "не"? В первом предложении, как я понимаю, работает правило, когда мы ставим тире между двумя словоформами, имеющими значение субъекта, объекта, обстоятельства и построенными по схемам *кто — чему, кто — куда, что — кому, что — куда, что — как, что — где*. Но по какому принципу ставится тире в последнем предложении?

И вопрос по поводу грамотности своего предложения. Будет ли правомерно написать "имеющими значениЯ", или правильно "имеющими значениЕ"?

Answer (score 4):

*И все кажется мне, что это — не настоящее...*

[**Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92) (справочник Розенталя)

> **7.** При подлежащем, выраженном словом ***это***, между главными членами предложения тире ставится в зависимости от логического выделения подлежащего и наличия паузы после него; ср.: ***Это** — **начало** всех начал. — **Это** неплохое **начало; Это** — **одиночество*** (Ч.). — ***Это дом** Зверкова* (Г.).

Обычно тире не ставится, если перед сказуемым стоит отрицание ***не***, но...

> Постановка тире в этом случае имеет целью логически и интонационно подчеркнуть сказуемое: *Но объяснение — не оправдание* (М. Г.); *Его взгляды на семейный этикет — не предрассудок ли это?*

Использовать множественное число слова ***значение***, думаю, правомерно, так как Вы пишете о **двух** словоформах с **разными** значениями.

Comment: Голос от меня: за ваш ответ и за правила Розенталя.

Answer (score 3):

**В чем актуальность Розенталя?**

Ценность правил Розенталя в том, что по примерам из его справочника можно понять **принцип письма,** а потом уже решать свою **конкретную** задачу. Давая **ссылку** на правило, мы в действительности указываем именно на  принцип решения **подобных задач**.

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

*И все кажется мне, что **это — не настоящее.**..*

1. Смотрим **грамматику:** СПП, придаточное изъяснительное. ***Это*** — подлежащее, выраженное указательным местоимением. ***Настоящее*** — субстантивированное слово в роли именного сказуемого.
2. Правила для такой грамматической структуры предполагают постановку **тире**, в том числе при наличии ***НЕ***. Тогда подлежащее будет выделено **логическим** ударением,  а после него делается пауза.
3. В общем случае (в этой теме) нам важно обозначить  паузой и тире  **границу** меду подлежащим и сказуемым, а иначе смысл сказанного будет сложно понять.

**ВЫВОД**

Таким образом, мы видим единство **трех принципов** пунктуации (семантика, грамматика, интонация) и в тоже время соответствие правилам Розенталя. **Что же еще-то нужно?**

Мы не всегда вспоминаем **о трех принципах,** но всегда имеем их в виду. Объяснять знаки без грамматики вообще нежелательно, семантика и интонация упоминаются по необходимости. А вот **ссылка на правило** — это основное  требование. Мы или сразу даем ссылку, или готовы ее дать в любой момент.

Answer (score 2):

**По какому учебнику изучал правописание Горький?**

Это известный труд академика **Я. К. Грота «Русское правописание» (1885 г.),** потом учебник переиздавался много раз.  И свои правила Грот тоже **не придумывал**,  а брал материал из других источников, а их было достаточно. **Преемственность знаний** можно видеть на протяжении длительного периода  **[от первых букварей](https://dzen.ru/a/ZPDbP50iIVm70Uig)** (1574 год) **до Розенталя.**

**[Вот еще пример.](https://dspl.ru/blog/pro-vystavki/v-polzu-yunoshestva-uchebniki-18-pervoy-poloviny-19-vv/)** Курганов Н. Г. **Российская универсальная грамматика**, или Всеобщее писмословие: предлагающее легчайший способ основательного учения русскому ящыку с седьмью присовокуплениями разных учебных и полезно-забавных вещей. СПб., 1769.

```
 Самый распространённый учебник русского языка и 
 грамматики второй половины 18 – начала 19 веков, 
 более известный под названием «ПИСЬМОВНИК». 
 Текст «Письмовника» постепенно дополнялся  в 
 дальнейших изданиях (он издавался 4 раза в 18 веке 
 и ещё 7 раз в первой половине 19 века). Например, в 
 неоконченной повести А. С. Пушкина «История села 
 Горюхина» (1830) вымышленный герой И. П. Белкин 
 говорит: «Чтение Письмовника долго было любимым 
 моим упражнением. Я знал его наизусть и, несмотря 
 на то, каждый день находил в нём новые незамеченные 
 красоты».
```

Самым масштабным событием в развитии русского правописания было принятие в 1956 году Правил русского письма – так был завершен  почти **300-летний путь**  развития **системы русского правописания**.

**Из предисловия:**

```
 Настоящие «Правила» должны служить основным ИСТОЧНИКОМ для 
 всех составителей учебников, словарей русского языка, 
 специальных словарей, энциклопедий и справочников. 
 «Правила» НЕ ЯВЛЯЮТСЯ УЧЕБНЫМ ПОСОБИЕМ для школьного 
 преподавания орфографии и пунктуации: как объем правил, так 
 и характер изложения их, вытекающие из специфических задач 
 свода, не соответствуют ни тому КОЛИЧЕСТВУ сведений, ни 
 тому МЕТОДУ ОБУЧЕНИЯ, которые установлены для школы».
```

Розенталь **составил эти учебные пособия,** и вот уже более
полувека вся страна изучает правописание по Розенталю.

Цитата из статьи «Ударные правила Розенталя» (philologist — ЖЖ (livejournal.com).

```
  Можно без преувеличения сказать, что **все люди 
  литературного труда в позднем СССР выросли на учебниках 
  Розенталя.** Преподаватели, журналисты, писатели, 
  драматурги – все знали это имя от своих школьных учителей 
  или университетских профессоров. Он не считал, разумеется, 
  что придумал правила русского языка – сам себя называл 
  черновым рабочим. Дескать, просто отыскал источники, 
  систематизировал полученные знания и изложил их в виде 
  справочников...
```

**По этим справочникам** мы и будем изучать правописание, **других вариантов нет.**

Comment: У вас нет вариантов, у кого-то другого есть.

Comment: И у кого же?...  Вроде бы все по правилам пишут. Корректоры, редакторы так не пропустят. В школах тоже правила. И т.д.

Comment: Ну и носитесь со своим Розенталем, мне не жалко.

Comment: РАН опишет,  а то что им делать-то?  А про бьюти-блогер и я могу сказать. Можете считать, что это несклоняемое  приложение  в препозиции. Сравнить: горе-охотник, золото-старушка у Розенталя, это его принцип.  Примеры: бьюти-бокс, бьюти-сфера. Слова пока не нормированы.

Comment: Некоторые слова с бьюти нормированы и внесены в некоторые словари неологизмов, например Шагаловой. Бьюти - это не приложение, а неизменяемое прилагательное в препозиции либо начальная часть сложного слова, поскольку бьюти это не второе название блогера, а признак его, сфера деятельности. Русский язык - не справочник Розенталя. Справочник Розенталя - лишь практическое пособие, не более того, авторская точка зрения. Смешно придираться к пунктуации Горького только потому что у Розенталя что-то там не так написано.

Comment: Я ни в коем случае не придирался к пунктуации Горького. Меня лишь заинтересовало, каким правилом ее можно объяснить. Естественно, всегда можно сослаться на пластичность русского языка и авторскую пунктуацию, и это будет правдой, но в данном случае мне захотелось разобраться с этим с точки зрения уже существующих норм.

Answer (score 1):

Я часто в недоумении от таких вопросов (и ответов). Почему-то многие считают, что русский язык, русский синтаксис и русская пунктуация представляют собой лишь свод тухлых розенталевских правил и что всё, что не описано в этих методичках или не соответствует им, должно либо отрицаться, либо подвергаться сомнению.

Почему язык Горького, пунктуация Горького (умершего в 1936 году) должны "подстраиваться" под какие-то там "правила" Розенталя (или кого-нибудь ещё), вышедшие намного позже произведений Горького?

Почему Горький поставил тире перед не? Потому что захотел, и точка.